# Change color in soliton image in tensorflow 2

Tags: python, image, tensorflow, colors

I am trying change the color of soliton images, in a resultant video using tensorflow 2 and python, but I am not sure how to go about it. At the moment it just shows different shades of green for the image:

[image]

How would I adjust the code to include red, blue and green for the components X, Y and G of the 2D soliton? I can see that the color in terms of `rgb` is included here:

```
def make_video_frame(rgb, indexing='ij'):
    if indexing == 'ij':
        rgb = [tf.transpose(channel) for channel in rgb]
    frame = tf.stack(rgb, axis=-1)
    frame = tf.clip_by_value(frame, 0.0, 1.0)
    return tf.cast(frame * 255, 'uint8').numpy()
```

See @ https://github.com/frostburn/tf2-model-g/blob/master/render_video.py#L33

and here:

```
print("Rendering 'Nucleation and Motion in G gradient in 2D'")
print("Lattice constant dx = {}, time step dt = {}".format(fluid_model_g.dx, fluid_model_g.dt))
min_G = -4.672736908320116
max_G = 0.028719261862332906
min_X = -3.8935243721220334
max_X = 1.2854028081816122
min_Y = -0.7454193158963579
max_Y = 4.20524950766914
for n in progressbar.progressbar(range(args.num_frames)):
    fluid_model_g.step()
    if n % args.oversampling == 0:
        rgb = [
            6*(-fluid_model_g.G + max_G) / (max_G - min_G),
            5*(fluid_model_g.Y - min_Y) / (max_Y - min_Y),
            0.7*(fluid_model_g.X - min_X) / (max_X - min_X),
        ]
        zero_line = 1 - tf.exp(-600 * fluid_model_g.Y**2)
        frame = make_video_frame([c * zero_line for c in rgb])
        writer.append_data(frame)
```

See @ https://github.com/frostburn/tf2-model-g/blob/master/render_video.py#L80

Comment: The X and G values are plotted, it's just that the Y values (corresponding to the green) are bigger, hence the resulting colors tending to green. The image is not "just" green, you can even see some shades of blue, in the second inner circle.